# Probability using Geometry: P($x+y<3$) same as P($x+y \leq 3$)?

Tags: probability, geometry

We are supposed to solve this using geometry, but other ways/insights are more than welcome.

*A point (x, y) is randomly chosen within the square with vetices (0,0), (0,2), (2,2) and (2,0). 
What is the probability that $x + y < 3$?*

Drawing $y = 3 - x$, I understand that the area of $x + y < 3$ represents $7/8$ of the 2 by 2 square's area, therefore the probability is $7/8$.

**But** what if we were asked about $x + y \leq 3$?

There should be a difference; however thinking geometrically I don't see how we could express that difference.
How would we "include" the line $y = 3 - x$ into our set of desired outcomes?

And if the probability is actually the same, why is that the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$P(x+y \le 3)-P(x+y < 3)
=P(x+y=3)
$.

But the set 
$\{(x, y) | x+y=3\}$
has area zero,
since it is a
segment of a straight line.

Therefore,
its probability is zero,
so
$P(x+y \le 3)=P(x+y < 3)$.

Note that if you are looking
at lattice points,
this will not be true.

Comment: But how can the probabilities be the same? I understand that a line has no area, but it doesn't make sense that the probabilities should be equal since $x+y \leq 3$ includes more solutions within the same sample space, names all the solutions where $x+y=3$

Comment: If you were to throw darts at the square, the probability of hitting the line exactly is 0, even though, well, the line is plainly there! But the probability of landing in a "fat" region: that's nonzero.

Comment: @Unit, but if you think in terms of sets, then the solution 1.9999999 + 1 is in both P($x+y < 3$) and P($x+y \leq 3$), but the solution 2 + 1 is only in P($x+y \leq 3$). 
How does that not change the probability?

Comment: If the probability of any particular single point was nonzero, then, there being no reason why that point is special, all points would have nonzero probability, and all these probabilities would be equal (again, because of lack of specialness).  Then the probability of a whole line would not even be defined, because it would be the "sum" of the probabilities of each of its (uncountably!) infinitely many points, which would be infinite. To get a reasonable mathematical theory, we *must* define probabilities of individual points to be zero.

Comment: @Unit, I think I understand the argument for mathematical coherence, but isn't there a paradox in the sense that if the probability of a single point is zero, when we add those up we should get a probability of zero? It's hard for me to make sense of the idea that taken by themselves, points have prob 0, but taken as an area they have probability of that area over total area. That doesn't seem like a reasonable theory.

Comment: Good old infinity. Always causing problems. In this case, the probability is *defined* as the area. Therefore, any set with an area of zero (such as lines and points) has probability of zero.

Comment: @martycohen, I was reading through some of my old questions and wanted to thank you again for your answer and comments. Now this makes total sense and it seems crazy I could've ever been confused about it, but I guess it always feels like that once you "get it".